# How to give focus to anchor tag without href="#"

Tags: css

How to give focus when using keyboard tab?

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
```

I tried using css like this

```
ui-datepicker-prev:focus { border:1px solid red}
```

But this doesn't work well. Anyone know ?

Comment: How about `href="javascript:void(0)"`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, class selector should start with a dot:

```
.ui-datepicker-prev:focus {border: 1px solid red; }
```

As for being able to use keyboard navigation for elements that are nonfocusable by default, setting `tabindex="0"` attribute should help.

Comment: An anchor with no href will be tabbable with tabindex="0", but hitting the Enter will not activate it as far as i know

Comment: @Ryan `href`-less `A` element has no default action, that’s OK given that it’s intended to be handled with JS.

Answer (score 13):

Either set **tabindex="0"** or specify **href="javascript:;"**, It should be focusable.

Answer (score 1):

tabindex="0" will make the focusable but not clickable with enter. href is needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

I ran into this same issue, browsers will not tab to `<a>` unless a `href` exists. I solved this by adding empty `href`'s to my anchor tags, like so

`<a href="">Link</a>`

Comment: This does worse than nothing, it directs you to the homepage.