# Accessibility Issues - Links won't tab through or expand to reveal hidden content

Tags: jquery, css, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I created a hide/reveal step-by-step component that shows content if you click on the step number.

It works as intended, but I'm having trouble ensuring its accessible.

- I can't seem to tab using my keyboard over the 1-4 links, even though they are `<a>`  tags.

```
<div class="progress-steps">
<a class="showSingle" target="1"></a>
<a class="showSingle" target="2"></a>
<a class="showSingle" target="3"></a>
<a class="showSingle" target="4"></a>
</div>
```

- I also want to ensure that the user can also activate the hidden content via the keyboard.

```
<section id="progress-content" class="hide">
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv"><h3>Initiation</h3>
  <p><strong>Fill out the </strong><a class="bold-link" href="https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form?EQBCT=b6923f4b9dc347f384936e342e5d2b58" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Project Request Form</a>: Each request goes through a review process to determine if the project is ready to be worked on.</p>
  </div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv"><h3>Planning</h3>
  <p><strong>Kickoff</strong>: After approval, we will schedule a meeting between all involved parties to discuss the scope and direction of the project.</p>
  </div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv"><h3>Execution</h3>
  <p><strong>We get to work!</strong> The plan will be carried out — involving all key stakeholders. The final product will be tested and implemented.</p>
  </div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv"><h3>Assessment</h3>
  <p><strong>Metrics for Success</strong>: After completion of the project, we will obtain sign-off of deliverables and revisit in 6-12 months to ensure stakeholders needs are met.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've tried playing around with the `:focus` and inserting `role="tab" aria-selected="true"` into the `<a>` tags.

Here's my code pen: https://codepen.io/ckatz/pen/gJmgbq

I want to make sure that anyone using a keyboard can use this component effectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give focus to anchor tag without href="#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476292/how-to-give-focus-to-anchor-tag-without-href)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to tab through by adding `tabindex="0"` to each of the links. This includes the tab links in the normal flow while tabbing through the site.

I also read that you actually *shouldn't* be using `aria-selected="true"` for all navigation links, only the currently selected one. Find out more here: [stefanjudis.com/blog/aria-selected-and-when-to-use-it](https://www.stefanjudis.com/blog/aria-selected-and-when-to-use-it/)

So your step selector would look like this instead:

```
<div class="progress-steps">
<a class="showSingle" target="1" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nils-tab"></a>
<a class="showSingle" target="2" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nils-tab"></a>
<a class="showSingle" target="3" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nils-tab"></a>
<a class="showSingle" target="4" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nils-tab"></a>
</div>
```

Although I couldn't get it to select the focused element with space or enter. I'll have to do some more research to figure out what's up with that!

Comment: Thank you! I think I figured out a way to get the steps to show the intended content using space or enter. I had to change the `<a>` to `<buttons>`.

Comment: Interesting limitation. Thanks for the heads up!